# Make snapshot dependecies build on the same branch

Tags: git, maven, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a build configuration which I explicitly tell on which branch to be build (`my-side-branch` for example).

Problem is that all of its snapshot dependencies uses the the default branch (`master`).

How can I make them build on the same checkout directory \ branch ? I couldn't find any suitable answer...

Comment: Do you have branch specifications setup on the dependent builds? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Configuringbranches

Comment: I tried to set one with `+:/refs/heads/%teamcity.build.branch%`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd, looks like you are right, the branch name is propagated to the depended build, all I had to do is to monitor them, thanks!